# flask can not connect mysql in docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

flask can not connect mysql in docker compose
in connect string, I already use db service name as host, still can't connect db
My docker-compose.yml:

```
  services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './api:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_CONFIG=development
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://root:xxxxx@mysql-db:3307/gaojiesi
      - SECRET_KEY=ZQbn05PDeA7v11
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    links:
      - mysql-db
    restart: unless-stopped

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql-db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=frikyalong
    ports:
        - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
        - ./db/mysql/conf/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf.d/
        - ./db/mysql/logs:/logs
        - ./db/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://root:xxxxx@mysql-db:3307/gaojiesi
```

to :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://root:xxxxx@mysql-db:3306/gaojiesi
```

port 3307 in not reachable from inside the container

Comment: sorry, I checked again, I change it to 3306 still can not connect mysql.